# Keep getting selenium cant be found even though i installed it

Tags: python, selenium, visual-studio-code

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\Python\GPUBuyer\Airis Tech Bot.py", line 1, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver as wd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
```

I try to run this script from vs code. i keep getting this error even though i installed selenium in the folder

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command "pip install selenium" to install selenium on the terminal, and then use the command "pip show selenium" to check whether the installation is successful.Executing again should solve the problem.